# Is there any way to encrypt video file in Darwin server?

Tags: darwin

Is there any way to encrypt video file(.mp4) in Darwin server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `openssl(1)` tool is probably available on your OS X system.

Start it with `openssl`, then enter:

```
aes-128-cbc -in <filename> -out <filename> -e
```

That will encrypt the file. To decrypt, run the same program and give the same arguments, but use `-d` instead of `-e`.